# Dealing with paths in MVC libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project and a class library just for saving and deleting images.

I have the path to those images stored in a variable as a relative path 
`Content\images\` that I reference inside the Save() and Delete() methods.

The save method works as I would think but the delete throws an error as it's relating the current path from the window directory.

```
// Works fine
File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Settings.ImagesPath, filename), binaryData);

// Error saying it cannot find the path in the C:\windows\system32\folder
File.Delete(Path.Combine(Settings.ImagesPath, filename));
```

I'd like to be able to switch between relative and absolute paths in my `Settings.ImagesPath` string but every SO article I've tried works for one scenario or the other. What's the best way to convert absolute or relative paths to some common way to deal with them?

Comment: What is the value you have in `Settings.ImagesPath` ?

Comment: You can try to use `Server.MapPath` to get absolute path from the relative one. The you can use `Path.Combine` to add file name.

Comment: @Shyju Content\images\ is the current value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Server.MapPath` method to generate the path to the location and use that in your `Path.Combine` method.

```
var fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Settings.ImagesPath), filename);
System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
```

Server.MapPath method returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path. In this case, `Server.MapPath(Settings.ImagesPath)` will return the physical file path to your `Content\images\` which is inside your app root.

You should do the same when you save the file as well.

You can also check the existence of the file before attempting to delete it

```
var fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Settings.ImagesPath), filename);
if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
}
```

Server.MapPath expects a relative path. So if you have an absolute value in the `Settings.ImagePath`, You can use the `Path.IsPathRooted` method to determine if it is a virtual path or not

```
var p = Path.Combine(Path.IsPathRooted(Settings.ImagesPath)
                            ? path : Server.MapPath(Settings.ImagesPath), name);

if (System.IO.File.Exists(p))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(p);
}
```

When you use the virutal path, make sure it start with `~`.

```
Settings.ImagesPath =   @"~\Contents\Pictures";
```

Comment: Would this also work if Settings.ImagesPath was an absolute path as well?

Comment: No. Server.MapPath expects a virtual path. You can have some logic to check whether it is an absolute path or virtual path and use Server.MapPath as needed

Comment: Can you add that to your example?

Comment: Also, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath doesn't start me at the root of my application, it includes the controller name in the path